# Python-telegram-bot send message to phone numbers

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-telegram-bot

I create a telegram bot with framework python-telegram-bot.
I have a little phone numbers,Now I want send message to phone numbers.
The phone numbers have an account in Telegram,and this is my codes:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, MessageHandler, Filters
def start_method(bot, update):
    bot.send_message(chat_id='Phone number', "Hello")
def main():
    updater = Updater(token='TOKEN')
    updater.dispatcher.add_handler(MessageHandler(Filters.text, start_method))
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But;this codes don't work and not give me an error!!!

How can I do???

Answer (score 5):

You can't do that at this time, since bots can't be first to chat, you have to give your users bot link like [t.me/Sean_Bot](https://t.me/Sean_Bot), and ask them to START.